# Get the list of all paths between 2 nodes

Tags: java

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong in here. I want to get the list of all paths between 2 given nodes in a graph. Any help would be very appriciated.

```
public class City {
    final private String id;  

      public City(String id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      public City getCity() {
    return node;
  }
  public int getCost() {
    return cost;
  }
}

public class Route {

    private final City node;
    private final int cost; 

      public Route(City node, int cost) {
        this.node = node;
        this.cost = cost;
      }
}

    public class Graph {

private final List<City> cities;
private final List<Route> routes;
private final Map<City, List<Route>> myGraph = new HashMap<City,List<Route>>();
private Queue<City> visited = new LinkedList<City>();
private Queue<City> beenThere = new LinkedList<City>();

 public Graph(List<City> vertexes, List<Route> edges) {
    this.cities = vertexes;
    this.routes = edges;
  }

  public String toString () {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        for (City c: myGraph.keySet()) 
            System.out.println(c + " -> " + myGraph.get(c));
        System.out.println();
        return s.toString();                
    }

  public void addNew (City vertex) {
        if (myGraph.containsKey(vertex)) 
            return;
        myGraph.put(vertex, new ArrayList<Route>());   
    }

  public void add (City from, City to, int cost) {
        this.addNew(from); 
        this.addNew(to);
        myGraph.get(from).add(new Route(to,cost));
        myGraph.get(to).add(new Route(from,cost));
    }

  public boolean contains (City vertex) {
        return myGraph.containsKey(vertex);
    }

 // public Route returnRoute

  public Queue<City> getNeighbors(City city) {
        Queue<City> neighbors = new LinkedList<City>();
        for (City c : myGraph.keySet()) {
            String c1 = c.toString();
            String city1 = city.toString();
            if (c1.equals(city1)) 
                neighbors.add(myGraph.get(c).get(0).getCity()); 
        }
        return neighbors;
        }

  public Queue<City> checkRoute(City node) {
      Queue<City> neighbors = new LinkedList<City>();
      neighbors = this.getNeighbors(node);
      for (City n : neighbors) 
              if(visited.contains(n))
                  break;
              else
          {
                  visited.add(n);
                  beenThere.add(n);
                  checkRoute(n);
              }

      return beenThere;
  }

  public List<Queue<City>> BFS(Graph graph, City from, City to) {
      List<Queue<City>> rute = new ArrayList<Queue<City>>();
      Queue<City> toVisit = new LinkedList<City>();
      toVisit.add(from);
      beenThere.add(from);
      while(!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
          City node = toVisit.remove();
          visited.add(node);
          Queue<City> neighbors = new LinkedList<City>();
          neighbors = this.getNeighbors(node);
          while(!neighbors.isEmpty()) {
              visited.add(neighbors.element());
              checkRoute(neighbors.remove());
          }
          if (beenThere.poll().equals(to))
              rute.add(beenThere);
          beenThere.clear();
          beenThere.add(from);
          //visited.clear();
      }
      return rute;
    }

    public void ReadFile() throws IOException  {
      String scan;
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\W7\\workspace\\AI-Lab1\\graph.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
        while((scan = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numberString =scan.split(" ");
            String from = numberString[0];
            City city1 = new City(from);
            String to = numberString[1];
            City city2 = new City(to);
            int cost = Integer.parseInt(numberString[2]);
            this.add(city1, city2, cost);
        }
        br.close();
  }
    }
```

the cities are read from a text file graph.txt:

```
Bucuresti Atena 1700
Bucuresti Budapesta 800
Paris Bucuresti 2000
Madrid Berlin 500
Kiew Moscova 800
Oslo Stokolm 590
Bucuresti Berlin 1500
Budapesta Berlin 500

public class Start {

    private static  List<City> nodes;
    private static List<Route> edges;

    private static void run () throws IOException {
        nodes = new ArrayList<City>();
        edges = new ArrayList<Route>();
        Graph graph = new Graph(nodes, edges); 
        graph.ReadFile();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Press:");
            System.out.println("[1] VIEW THE GRAPH");
            System.out.println("[2] GET THE SHORTEST PATH");
            try {
                String s = br.readLine();
                if(s.equals("exit"))
                    return;
                int option=Integer.parseInt(s);
                if (option == 1 ) {
                    System.out.println("The graph is:" );
                    System.out.println(graph);
                    //getGraph();
                    System.out.println("========================");
                }
                if (option == 2) {
                    System.out.println("\tGive source vertex : ");
                    String source = br.readLine();
                    City from =  new City(source);
                    System.out.println("\tGive destination vertex : ");
                    String destination = br.readLine();
                    City to = new City(destination);
                    //getShortestPath(graph,source,destination);
                    System.out.println(graph.BFS(graph, from, to));
                    System.out.println("========================");
                }
                if (option == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Please insert city:");
                    String c = br.readLine();
                    City city = new City(c);
                    System.out.println(graph.getNeighbors(city));
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
          run();

}
}
```

This returns an empty list and I don't understand why...

Comment: Exactly which method and with what parameters always returns an empty list?

Comment: The "rute" list should contain all the paths at the end but it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have:

```
if (beenThere.poll().equals(to)) {
  rute.add(beenThere);
}
```

To evaluate equality of one of your own personal Objects, you need to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for that class.

Otherwise, two objects will never be equal unless they are the exact same object in memory. Add these two methods to your `City` class:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
  return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
return true;
  if (obj == null)
return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
return false;
  City other = (City) obj;
  if (id == null) {
if (other.id != null)
  return false;
  } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
return false;
  return true;
}
```

Another issue is that you are clearing `beenThere` this also clears the value in your `ArrayList` since they both refer to the same object in memory. To understand, try playing with the following code where you comment out the `clear()` method to see the difference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Queue<Integer>> rute = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();
  Queue<Integer> beenThere = new LinkedList<Integer>();

  beenThere.add(1);
  beenThere.add(2);
  beenThere.add(3);
  rute.add(beenThere);

  beenThere.clear(); // run this code with this commented out to see the difference

  System.out.println(rute.toString());
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. It still returns an empty list

Comment: Another issue may be that you are clearing `beenThere` The same copy of `beenThere` is held in your `ArrayList`, so when you clear `beenThere` you are also clearing it in `rute`

Comment: @user3421241 I have just verified that this is exactly the problem

Comment: I have to clear that list every time I find a path, if I don't clear I would have all the cities one after another, in the order they have been visited..

Comment: Try reinstantiating instead of using `clear`. Like this: `beenThere = new LinkedList<City>();`

Comment: Not working :( I feel so bad about this project. I worked all day on it and I can't make it work..

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently too low to comment. But in your Graph class, getNeighbours method you've got a variable called *myGraph* however I cannot see the declaration anywhere.

Comment: I forgot to paste it in here. I've updated the question with more code

Comment: I cannot see how myGraph is being populated. You're initialising empty data collections there. Could you provide any further information for this please? An issue I'm currently seeing is                         neighbors.add(myGraph.get(c).get(0).getCity()); -- Even if your city has many routes, it will only go for the first city in the list. This appears to be a flaw in the logic. Further code would help.

Comment: Can you add the main call too please?

Comment: I added the Start class